# Remove multiple 'ThisWorkbook' modules from Excel VBA editor

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Within the VBA editor, I have found duplicate instances of the 'ThisWorkbook' module seen in this screenshot:

[image]

I would like to delete these extra instances, but do not know how.

`ThisWorkbook1` is now the system recognized module with all my Sheet numbers now having a 1 appended to the end of them I.e. Sheet11, 21, 31, 41, 51, 61. I have no idea how the other modules came into existence. Can anyone assist?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An [excel-vba](/questions/tagged/excel-vba) `Project` is hosted in a `Workbook`... seeing two `Workbook` objects under a single project is very worrying (and looking at the icons the VBE is using for the "ghost worksheets", it seems there's even more *workbook* objects than that) - I'd suggest you export all modules and copy the *sane* worksheet/workbook code into a new file (I wouldn't even try to *open* the ghost copies), and destroy that one.

Your project is most likely corrupted in some way.

Comment: Yeah - my thoughts as well. It's just that I've got a large power pivot model sitting underneath this which is populated with queries. While I can copy the sheets to a new book (along with the model), the queries all get lost. Thinking I might have to start from scratch and build again though...

Answer (score 2):

I appreciate this page is a bit old, however, as my users are using Excel 2019/Excel 365 and we're still seeing this popping up a couple of times a year (so fairly rare), I'll add my findings.

Users raised concerns with me when their sheets were crashing when opened from the network (worked when copied to their local PC). When I discovered the ghost sheets and extra "This Workbook" versions, I tried restoring an earlier version, but, all old versions were suffering from similar issues.
The Excel files I'm seeing this on are ones that are used across our WAN, they often crash during saving. Consequently the destination folder contains a number of *.tmp files. So I believe it is occurring as the sheet is not saving correctly/being corrupted during SAVE.

I fixed this by following Ricardo's solution above, so:

- Save the file under a new name, without macros (ie as *.xlsx)
- Close the XLSX version and reopen, check ghost sheets and extra 'This Workbook' have disappeared
- Save the new sheet with macros enabled (e.g *.xlsm)
- Copy VBA macros over from old broken sheet to new sheet (I did this by creating new modules the copy/pasting the code, however, I'm sure exporting/importing the modules would also work).

A later version of this corruption is where the macros stopped working, when I looked via the VBA editor the code doesn't exist. Double-clicking on a sheet or module object does nothing (no code window appears, not even an empty one), so the corruption has spread to the code objects.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but same happened to me in a large project.

But this is what I did to solve it:

1. Use [Rubberduck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) tools to export the project's code into a folder
2. Save the file to `xlsx` format (no macros)
3. Close and reopen the file
4. Import all code to the project (you can drag and drop classes and non worksheets/workbooks modules, for the latter you may copy paste the code)
5. Save it as `xlsm` (macro-enabled)
6. Close and reopen the file